# Stuck installing flask vscode

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I am a little new to python code, but more to flask. I have a Windows 10 64 bit OS, I have opened from a friend a python file that contains flask in VSCode, following some tutorial videos on Youtube I learned about flask and installing flask on vsCode but flask doesn't register as installed.

So step by step:

1.I made a venv in the VScode console using: `python -m venv venv` command then activated it in the scripts directory.

2.then used the `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the required packages here is the list or the requirements.txt (flask bolded):

- appnope==0.1.0
- backcall==0.1.0
- blinker==1.4
- Click==7.0
- decorator==4.3.0
- **Flask==1.0.2**
- Flask-DebugToolbar==0.10.1
- Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
- Flask-WTF==0.14.2
- ipython==7.18.1
- ipython-genutils==0.2.0
- itsdangerous==0.24
- jedi==0.13.1
- Jinja2==2.10
- MarkupSafe==1.1.1
- parso==0.3.1
- pexpect==4.6.0
- pickleshare==0.7.5
- prompt-toolkit==2.0.5
- psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
- ptyprocess==0.6.0
- Pygments==2.2.0
- simplegeneric==0.8.1
- six==1.11.0
- SQLAlchemy==1.3.20
- traitlets==4.3.2
- wcwidth==0.1.7
- Werkzeug==0.16.0
- WTForms==2.2.1
- cffi==1.14.3

3.Even after flask is installed by this txt document I still get the following error:

[screenshot of visual studio code window after flask is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQZSg.png)

notice the squiggly lines under the flask title still have not disappeared.

So simply I need to know what have I done wrong in vsCode, why is flask not active even though it was installed?

As someone on stackoverflow mentioned here is what the errors display:

[list of errors after install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Aok5.png)

[result of checking flask version and then attempting pip install flask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOP7U.png)

Let me know if further information is required.

Comment: are you certain the virtual environment has been activated?

Comment: blue bar at the bottom, second from the left

Comment: Please can you show the actual error. The *squiggly* lines only suggest an error, not what it is. Chances are you just haven't set your environment up properly.

Comment: If setting the correct settings feels too much, PyCharm might be a better IDE for you to use when coding in Flask. VS Code has given my similar issues before in terms of Flask, whilst PyCharm did not.

Comment: Even with the IDE issue, does your application run?

Comment: no the app doesn't run because flask will not work, I have added a screenshot of the error list.It may be more than flask is not working, I will consider switching application as an alternative but it will bug me if this is still not resolved. I will try running a test app without someone else's code and see if problem persists, but anyone else has any idea why this is happening then pls comment thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to edit inside your [Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations).

Press `Ctrl + Shift + P`, search "Open Workspace Settings (JSON)", and click `enter`.

Check for the following and add if necessary:

```
"python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python",    # /path/to/your/venv/bin/python
```

Comment: Ok so when I opened "Workspace Settings (JSON)" this file was empty except for curly braces { }. This part where it says: "python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python",    # /path/to/your/venv/bin/python I know my python program is located in "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32" but don't know how to re route the program to that location. By putting in G:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe I get an error. because G:\ drive is not recognised how do I get around this?

Comment: I can't tell what you mean. If it was empty, did you add the line of code above? Or are you saying that line was already in the file?

Comment: yes I added the line of code but then realised I need to point it to the python directory, so how do I point it to another drive? because I have python on the G:\ drive also as per the above example I am missing the /bin/python directory in venv is there a command to do that?

Comment: the file "settings.json" now reads: {"python.pythonPath": G:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe} but again this dosen't work because "G" is not recognised.

Comment: No, it needs to point to the one inside your venv folder, as that is the Python file being run when you *activate* your venv. If you directory is set up like a Flask project, the one in my solution should be the path you need.

Comment: no that directory "bin" is missing from venv, so did I miss something when made the venv folder using "python -m venv venv" ??

Comment: Yeah, that is wrong. I would start again. Looking at your post again, make sure to start your venv using `python3 -m venv venv`, not `python`.

Comment: Ok so apparently when I ran python3 -m venv venv, then pointed to the file in settings.json all the code removed from the file when i saved and restarted the workspace, i then got directed to a page saying python.pythonPath setting is being removed from all 3 scopes - User, workspace, workspace folder.
A new user setting python.defaultInterpreterPath is introduced... which is meant as a replacement for python.pythonPath in user scope, but not in workspace scope.
A VSCode internal storage is introduced which will now store the interpreter settings in the workspace & workspace folder scope.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you provided, the reason is that this module is not installed in the current environment, or the related files of this module are damaged. Please refer to the following:

1. The python environment used by the VS Code terminal is not the python environment currently used by VS Code.

   Please use the command "`pip show flask`" to check whether the module "flask" is installed in the expected environment:

   [image]

   (If it does not display the module information, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new terminal, and it will automatically enter the environment selected in the lower left corner.)
2. The related files of the module are damaged or incompatible.

   Please find the installation folder of the module "flask" in this virtual environment:
   Then try to remove or delete it, and reinstall it in VS Code. (`pip install flask`)

   [image]

In addition, please try to reload VS Code after installing the module.

run:

[image]

More reference: [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: I have added a screenshot after attempting the above (last screenshot added). still no joy, am i still missing something?

Comment: @laza0001265 -Have you tried reloading VS Code? Please use the command "_python --version_" or "_pip --version_" to check whether the python currently used by the VS Code terminal is the same as the lower left corner.

Comment: it has been saying the pip installation is older, is that a problem?

Comment: @laza0001265 -Do you mean it displays: "_WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.0.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command._"?  This is an update The 'pip' suggestion does not affect the installation of the module. Is "flask" available now?

Comment: I tried removing all my extensions on VSCode and now the red lines under flask have disappeared. But now I cannot run the code, what should I do in VSCode to test the python to see if it is working?

Comment: @laza0001265 -To use Python in VS Code, it requires us to install the "Python" extension in VS Code. You could refer to this document: [Flask Tutorial in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask)

Answer (score 0):

To install any python library on vscode, you should do on python directory.
for example:
"**C:/Users/sahithpixels/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe -m pip install flask**" this is how we can install any package, hope this helps :).